# Html and node js

Tags: node.js, asp.net, express

I am an ASP.NET dev and I want to explore nodejs/express. In ASP.NET you can control raw html from the backend. I want to have a button click toggle the visibility of a div. I know you can do this on the frontend but is there anyways to do this on server side?

This is my code so far

```
const e = require('express');
var express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
var date;
//var http = require('http');
//var proxiedHttp = require('findhit-proxywrap').proxy(https);
var app = express();
var filePath = '';

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
// send records as a response
console.log(req);
filePath = path.resolve(\__dirname, 'index.html');
res.sendFile(filePath);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the server-side control of a div's visibility in Node.js and Express by using a templating engine like [EJS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ejs) and defining an endpoint to handle the toggle action.

1. Install EJS

```
npm install ejs
```

2. Setup EJS in your app

```
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
```

3. Create a folder named `views` (this is proper convention when using ejs). Inside it, create a file called `index.ejs`. An example of it looks something like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Toggle Div</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="window.location.href='/toggle'">Toggle Div</button>
    <div style="display: <%= visibility %>;">
        This is a toggled div.
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

You can normally just use a variable to control visibility, and send a response based on this variable's value. However, assuming you want to manage this per-client, you'll want to use a piece of middleware called `express-session`, which helps you individualize your users.

1. Install express session with `npm install express-session`
2. Configure

```js
const session = require('express-session');

app.use(session({
  secret: 'secret-key',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true
}));
```

3. Modify the endpoints to use it

```js
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  if (req.session.visibility === undefined) {
    req.session.visibility = 'block';
  }
  res.render('index', { visibility: req.session.visibility });
});

app.get('/toggle', function (req, res) {
  req.session.visibility = req.session.visibility === 'block' ? 'none' : 'block';
  res.redirect('/');
});
```

The visibility of the div is stored in the **session**, so it's unique to each client. If one client toggles the div, it won't affect other clients.

*Sidenote: Writing this post has made me reflect upon the javascript everywhere paradigm.*